# Is there a way to detect if a cat is sleeping? 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've searched for cat nbt data and also checked in-game but no dice. It doesn't seem to have a "Sleeping" tag like that of a fox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no NBT tag to detect a sleeping cat. Why is that? NBT is not a format that is constantly manipulated during gameplay. It's just save data, the data that Minecraft uses to remember your world state the next time you open your world.

The only things that are stored in NBT is stuff that needs to be remembered if you close and reopen your world. Sitting and standing is one of those properties, but sleeping is *not*. Think about it a little. Cats only sleep when you're sleeping, and you can't leave the game without leaving the bed. And when you leave the bed, the cat no longer sleeps. Therefore, the cat is guaranteed not to be sleeping when you leave your bed, meaning that this data does *not* need to be stored in NBT, and hence, never is.

So it appears you're out of luck. I may be able to come up with a workaround, but I haven't yet, so I'm delivering this partial answer to you.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Though I do have a question. From what I understood NBT data only remembers stuff that doesn't change constantly. So if that were the case, why do foxes have sleeping, crouching, and sitting tags when those are very often manipulated during gameplay? And thank you for the help :)

Comment: @FerrynFox You are slightly wrong. Look at my answer again. NBT remembers stuff that needs to be saved *if you close and reopen the world*. Of course this stuff changes constantly, but it needs to be remembered if you close and reopen the world. *(If you want to **really** get technical, the NBT isn't actually changing constantly as the fox moves about. All that stuff happens in-memory, not in NBT. When you close your world, the current state is saved to the NBT so it can be remembered.)*